# The reason for MonadState get and put?

Tags: state, monads, haskell

I'm reading the Monads chapter in Real World Haskell (chapter 14).
A function is [defined](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html#Random.hs:getRandom) as follows:

```
type RandomState a = State StdGen a
getRandom :: Random a => RandomState a
getRandom =
    get >>= \gen ->
    let (val, gen')= random gen in
    put gen' >>
    return val
```

I don't really understand the purpose of the get and put functions here.
I rewrote the function as following which seems to do the same thing and is more concise:

```
getRandom2 :: Random a => RandomState a 
getRandom2= State $ \ s -> random s
```

So my question is: **What is the purpose of get and put in general?**

Comment: Just in this case, or the purpose of `get` and `put` in general? Their use can be easier explained in the latter case…

Comment: In general; I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bit of a coincidence that `random` happens to have exactly the same type signature/usage pattern as the inner function of the `State` monad (and indeed in this case you could be even more concise, if perhaps more confusing, with `getRandom2 = State random`).

However, more generally that won't apply, and then `get` and `put` are convenient plumbing pieces whose meaning is perhaps clearer than writing the inner function directly. They also help to abstract from the precise representation used by `State` - they are actually class members of the more general class `MonadState`, so you can write more polymorphic code by using them.

Comment: I have one more question -- how the *put* keep the new state for next call? The output of *put* is ignored, i can not figure it out. Please help me out. Thx.

Comment: That's part of the internal plumbing of the `State` monad. The monadic output of `put` is of type `()` to indicate that it isn't a useful value.

Comment: Thx for the reply. But i do not fully understand. Do it mean the *put* have some side effect? Can you explain how it store the new state? Thx.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question, this seems a bit long for a discussion in comments.